# Need to duplicate/fork or redirect entire system console output for all apps and the system/kernel messages

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am developing the test suit in C++ for the PDA-like device running Linux.
While working with development kit I have access to a serial console with system output. Eventually my software should be used on closed box with no console output and Ethernet connection available. I would like to be able to duplicate the entire console output (not only my code output, that would be easy). Any suggestions?

The SSH to the device is working, but apparently it only echoes the commands and responses I send from the remote console. I would like to sniff in on all system output from previously started applications and kernel.

Comment: How about making your software to write log files?

Comment: I can make system to do remote logging, as well as my app, but I cannot make third party apps to log everything they output to stderr/stdout.